# checking the integrity of aes ciphertext

Tags: javascript, aes

When decrypting an AES ciphertext, how does one check if the ciphertext is valid?
For instance:

```
Encryption Key: stackoverflow
Plaintext: Hello World!
AES Ciphertext: 3AN75bE2LlGR957fjjd5WOfRmdY=
```

When it is decrypted using the same encryption key, the plaintext result would be `Hello World!`

However, if i use a different key:

```
Encryption Key: stackexchange
AES Ciphertext: 3AN75bE2LlGR957fjjd5WOfRmdY=
Plaintext Result: ]o+ãTy¹¶Ïâ
```

Is there a way to verify that the Plaintext result is valid and that the specified encryption key is correct?

I'm writing a JS implementation using http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html.

Comment: A password is not the same as a key. A key should contain bytes with any value. You may need to use a PBKDF function to calculate the key from the password (but even then you should use a strong password).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure: encrypt a serialized json object that holds your plaintext instead of just the plaintext. If it doesn't deserialize it's not the correct key

Serialize and encrypt this:

`{"p": "Hello World!"}`

When decrypting the chance of getting `{"p":"` prefix is 1:2^48 and suffix `"}` 1:2^16. The decryption of the plaintext also has to be valid for json value. This means less than 1:2^64 chance of false-positive in by just checking if the decrypted text can be deserialized and has `p` value, good enough for most applications.

If you *really* insist you can include another field where you'd store the first character of your plaintext:

`{"p": "Hello World!","v":"H"}`

...but I think it's an overkill to have a verification chance for false-positive of 1:2^128

Comment: wouldn't that be a weak way of checking? what if the decrypted output actually yields to something like `[34656458974]`?

Comment: It's quite unlikely to get the right format for json to be deserialized correctly. If you want to further limit the chance you can add another field to the json object to contain an additional marker, such as the first 4 characters from the plaintext. No need of MD5s and other heavy hash functions, 4 characters to match makes for 1:2^32 chance, multiplied by the already tiny chance the json to be correct

Comment: @StenPetrov although you are good in calculating values, you should really read a good book on cryptography. Learn about Message Authentication Codes and padding oracle attacks. If you've really understood all that, then start giving advice. I would heartily recommend Crypto I at Coursera, if you are up to it...

Comment: @owlstead there is a spot between "not-secured" and "overkill" that provides the best feasible security at the least possible cost. Law of diminishing returns would tell you that at some point you'd be spending all your time hardening your security to only improve it by an extremely small margin. By all means - adding a known prefix to a message isn't an ideal plan as it would reduce the effort of an attacker to just one block of decryption. A post in SO about cryptography is looking for that sweet effort/payoff spot, I don't expect NSA to ask security questions here.

Comment: @StenPetrov You act as if adding a MAC or using an authenticating cipher is like rocket science. If security is not applied correctly you may as well Base 64 encipher it. Your scheme is directly attackable by padding oracle attacks if used over a network. That means less than 128 tries per byte to crack it. And that's just the start. What if your starting string is exactly one block? How difficult do you think it would be to get a match if the ending `}` is also at the start of a block?

Comment: @owlstead I take your concern seriously but I'm not clear how your attack works. Please write some pseudo code. Also: how is it possible to encrypt any file if all of them have some standard prefixes? how is this different from encrypting a zip file which has a "PK" prefix?

Comment: @StenPetrov I am not going to explain all that to you. You should learn crypto before giving advice PERIOD.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if the ciphertext is correct is to use a MAC (e.g. HMAC using SHA-256) over the ciphertext and additional parameters like the IV or an authenticated cipher like GCM. If you use a MAC that uses a block cipher you should certainly use a separate key.

Checking a known value (as in the accepted answer) makes you vulnerable against all kind of attacks and certainly should not be used over a transport protocol because of padding & plaintext oracle attacks.